# Remove website http/https while adding URL

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-fields

In my custom field, users add their site URls. I want to display them like this example.com not http//example.com/. I want to remove the http/https. This is just for the display purpose.

```
<?php

$site = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'url', true );

echo '<a class="user-website" href="'.$site.'">'.$site.'</a>';
?>
```

While display, it displays the entire URL like http://example.com in a link. I want to remove the protocol and display like [example.com](http://example.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$site = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'url', true );
$site_without_http = trim( str_replace( array( 'http://', 'https://' ), '', $site ), '/' );

echo '<a class="user-website" href="'.$site.'">'.$site_without_http .'</a>';

?>
```

Comment: An improvement will be to add the count parameter in str_replace like this :
`$site_without_http = str_replace( array( 'http://', 'https://' ), '', $site,1 );`

Comment: Thanks it works. Thank you but it still adds a trailing slash example.com/. Actually I added the site like this http://example.com/

Comment: Why? I assumed the URL was valid and a valid URL can have only one complete prefix.

Comment: I have updated my answer to remove the trailing slash, if any.

Comment: Thanks once again @technoh. However, I am getting this fatal error with your updated one

Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in...

Comment: Right, I misplaced a parenthesis. The (new) update should fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Technoh. It works like a charm. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

just http:// or https://

```
preg_replace(/\w+:\/\//, "", $string);
```

also www.

```
preg_replace(/\w+:\/\/w{3}\./, "", $string);
```